# An SDK Target must be specified

Tags: android

I'm really new at this. I'm following the book "Android" by O'Reilly press a little outdated, I'm using Pulsar for Mobile Java Developers. Build id: 20090920-1017 I go to File, New Project, Android, Android Project. I enter "Hello World" for Project Name. Then I get "An SDK Target must be specified." There is a check box but it says "no target specified".

How do I get this resolved and how do I get to the command line?

Answer (score 17):

You need to choose one of the SDKs in the **Build Target** section.

If there is none listed, cancel the dialog, and go to menu **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Android**, specify the SDK location (`android-sdk-windows` directory on Windows), and press **Apply**.

If you still don't get any **Target Name** listed, you need to install the SDK first. Cancel the dialog, and go to menu **Window** -> **Android SDK and AVD Manager**. Click **Available Packages** and select e.g. **SDK Platform Android 2.0, API 5, revision 1** then click **Install Selected**.

Comment: My problem was the second step.  Why are the install errors so subtle :( -Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note you may need to restart eclipse to get the Apply button to actually refresh available targets.

Answer (score 2):

I second to Yuku's answer but my case was I didn't have slash at the end of directory..

This is for Eclipse though it should be similar.

**Window -> Preference -> Android**

Then you see **SDK Location:**

It should be something like:

**/android/android-sdk-linux_86/**

To make sue it is correct, click on Apply button and you should see the list of android target names show up in the same dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

If your target list appears blank, play with the Eclipse font size. I had to drop my dialog font size down to 5pt/courier new to actually see any choices there.

See http://blog.rowancrane.com/2009/12/27/eclipse-new-android-project-cant-select-build-type-target for more information about this